Reading Meta public groups feed I'm a member of
I'm building a webapp to help house hunters find the house. I was trying to read feeds of public Meta groups related to rentals.
From what I understand the group admin has to install my app and give me the access token. But I got to know that groups API is deprecated from v19.0.
Is there any official alternate or workaround that you guys know or are using in your own use case? Thanks.

"But I got to know that groups API is deprecated from v19.0." - says who? Neither https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v21.0/group/feed nor https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v21.0/group mention anything in that regard. (And both pages allow selection of API versions up to the current v21, to get the specific documentation for that version.)
